# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'ch' in hi

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular 1.6, passing actions up (from a presentational component to a controller component), I got stocked on this:

Chat (Controller component)

```
const Chat = ['messages', function (ms) {
    ...
    this.sendMessage = (userInput) => {
        ms.sendMessage(userInput)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            })
    }
}]
```

Html Template:

```
<div class="messages">
    <conversation messages="ch.messages" ng-if="ch.messages" ></conversation>
    <user-input send="ch.sendMessage(userInput)"></user-input>
</div>
```

UserInput Component (Presentational component):

```
const UserInput = function () {
    ...
    this.checkAndSend = () => {
        this.send(this.input)
        this.input = this._clear()
    }
}

angular
    .module('chatbot-andrea')
    .component('userInput', {
        bindings: {
            send: '&'
        },
        ...
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a terrible mistake, as [velesin.io](https://velesin.io/2016/05/18/communication-between-angular-1-5-components/) explains

> "This is because the '&' binding is not really a callback function but
>   an expressions, and the title and description are not function
>   parameters but variables visible in the scope of the expression
>   context"

So using,

```
this.send(this.input)
```

never would not work. Instead of that you have to use:

```
this.send({userInput: this.input})
```

Codelord.net also explained [in a straightforward way](http://www.codelord.net/2016/05/13/understanding-angulars-and-binding/).